# How does the c++ container "set" indenify two equal keys?

Tags: c++, stl, set

Its declaration is as follows:

`template<class T,class Compare=less<T>,class Alloc=allocator<T>> class set;`

As we know, there are no two equal keys in a "set". It use "Compare"(the default is `less<T>`) to compare two keys, which means it can only know one key is less(`less<T>` returns `true`) or not less(`less<T>` returns `false`) than the other.

How can `set` avoid the existence of two equal keys?

Comment: template<class T,class Compare=less<T>,class Alloc=allocator<T>> class set;

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[`std::set`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set) determines uniqueness of elements as follows.

(emphasis mine)

> Everywhere the standard library uses the Compare requirements,
>   uniqueness is determined by using the equivalence relation. In
>   imprecise terms, **two objects `a` and `b` are considered equivalent if
>   neither compares less than the other: `!comp(a, b) && !comp(b, a)`**.